# selenium XPATH to identify td inside table

Tags: c#, html, selenium, xpath, automation

I have a table in which there are multiple rows.I want xpath to identify div with class = 'rowaction'(which can be in any td), but the only input i have is the string 'TTD'(which can be in any td).Based on 'TDD' i want to identify the div.Below is my HTML structure

```html
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <div> 
            <div class="rowaction"/>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
    <div> 
            <div />
            <span>
                <span>TTD</span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>..</tr>
<tr>..</tr>
</tbody>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is only one `td` that contains a `div` with that `class` per row

```
//span[contains(text(),'TTD')]/ancestor::tr//div[@class='rowaction']
```

Breakdown:

Find the span that contains the text 'TTD' (or exact text `[text()='TTD']`)

```
//span[contains(text(),'TTD')]
```

Get the row that contains that `span`

```
/ancestor::tr
```

Find a `div` in that row that has the exact `class` name 'rowaction'

```
//div[@class='rowaction']
```

That's all. If the `class` has other stuff going on, you could do a `contains(@class, 'rowaction')` as well.

And just to be complete, the forward axis approach:

```
//tr[descendant::span[contains(text(),'TTD')]]//div[@class='rowaction']
```